# javascript displaying dropdown list title

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list that is by javascript and it is working fine.
 The question is how do i display out the title (YES/NO) of the dropdown.

```
 function createSelect2(tag) {
 var select = document.createElement("select");
 select.id = "select-" + rowNumber;
 var array = [{
  title: "YES!",
  value: "return 0;"
 },
 {
  title: "NO",
  value: "return 1231 * area;"
 }
 ];
 tag.appendChild(select);
```

i tried using the below method in another function but it just could not work

```
var h = document.getElementById("tag");
var yesno = h.options[h.selectedIndex].text;
```

Please advice thannkss

Comment: you want to create two option tag with one is "yes" and other is "no" right?

Comment: @ChitraNandpal yes

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<div id = "tag">

</div>

<script>
function createSelect2(tag) {
var select = document.createElement("select");
var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
var opt2 = document.createElement("option");

opt1.value = "return 0;";
opt1.text = "YES";
opt1.title = "YES!"

opt2.value = "return 1231 * area;";
opt2.text = "NO!";
opt2.title = "NO!"

select.add(opt1, null);
select.add(opt2, null);

tag.appendChild(select);
}

createSelect2(document.getElementById("tag"));
</script>

</html>
```

maybe not title but text

Comment: select.add(opt1, null);
select.add(opt2, null);

Comment: do you add option in select element??

Comment: this is just a part of my whole project

Comment: <div id="tag">

<select><option value="return 0;" title="YES!">YES</option><option value="return 1231 * area;" title="NO!">NO!</option></select></div>

Comment: check chrome development tool correctly has this value   and i have to take course so I may be late check your apply

Comment: i have update the question pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483609/displaying-out-drop-down-list-only-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["Yes", "No"];
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = arr[i];
        option.value = arr[i];
        var select = document.getElementById("tag");
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i need it in javascript as the it is ald 90% done and it is all with js.

Comment: ok i have updated code,please let me know if it works for u :)

Comment: i have update the question pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483609/displaying-out-drop-down-list-only-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to write and append HTML and stick with a more JavaScript approach, the new option can be appended by creating a `new option object`.

> **Syntax:** new Option( text, value, defaultSelected, selected )

Check this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById( 'container' ),
    select = document.createElement( 'select' );

select.options.add( new Option( 'YES!', 0, true, true ) );
select.options.add( new Option( 'NO', 1231 ) );
div.appendChild( select );

select.addEventListener( 'change', function () {
  var selectedIndx = this.selectedIndex;
    console.log( 'Title: ' + this.options[ selectedIndx ].label + '  Value: ' + this.options[ selectedIndx ].value + '  Default: ' + this.options[ selectedIndx ].defaultSelected )
} );
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: i have update the question pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483609/displaying-out-drop-down-list-only-using-javascript