# dropdown display just js

Tags: javascript

I have a few dropdown lists that are by javascript and it is working fine.
The question is how do I display out the title of the first dropdown.

I have commented on the place that cant work

```
var h = document.getElementById("createSelect");
var textdisplay = h.options[h.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: The id "createSelect" doesn't seem to exist. What are you trying to get in your "h" variable? Also, there are multiple "select-0" (and "…-1" etc…) ids. That's incorrect as ids must be unique!

Comment: @TakitIsy var h is the title of the dropdown. so how can i do this?

Comment: As far as I understand, there isn't any title at the moment. What do you exactly mean by "title"? From which dropdown do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which receives an array and a string and return title of spesific item. like this

```
function getTitle(arr, val) {
  var item = arr.find(function(itm) {
    return itm['value'] == val;
  });
  return item['title'];
}
```

Use this function for array you want. for example title of first array

```
var textdisplay = getTitle(arr1, fId);
```

And add that where you want as output

```
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML +=
  "Answer " +
  ++answer +
  ") " +
  area +
  " ----" +
  func(area) +
  "<br>" +
  amount / discount +
  "<br>" +
  soilamount +
  "<br>" +
  textdisplay;
```

Use this code.

```js
var rowNumber = 0;
var arr1 = [{
    title: "10mm",
    value: "return 2;"
  },
  {
    title: "20mm",
    value: "return 2;"
  },
  {
    title: "30mm",
    value: "return 3;"
  },
  {
    title: "40mm",
    value: "return 4;"
  },

  {
    title: "title 1",
    value: "return Math.min( Math.max(2 / 100 * supposearea + 11.7222222222222, 9.5), 11.5 );"
  },
  {
    title: "title 2",
    value: "return Math.min(Math.max(2 / 100 * supposearea + 10.2222222222222, 8), 10);"
  },
  {
    title: "title 3",
    value: "return Math.min( Math.max(2 / 200 * supposearea + 11.7222222222222, 9.5), 11.5 );"
  },
  {
    title: "title 4",
    value: "return Math.min(Math.max((2/200*supposearea + 13.7222222222222),11.5),13.5);"
  }
];
var arr2 = [{
    title: "Original",
    value: "0.65"
  },
  {
    title: "35% Discount",
    value: "1"
  }
];
var arr3 = [{
    title: "No Soil",
    value: "return 0;"
  },
  {
    title: "Soil",
    value: "return Math.min(Math.max((2*(areas) + 3), 2),4);"
  }
];

function createSelect(tag, id, array) {
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.id = id + "-" + rowNumber;

  tag.appendChild(select);

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = array[i].value;
    option.text = array[i].title;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}

function getTitle(arr, val) {
  var item = arr.find(function(itm) {
    return itm['value'] == val;
  });
  return item['title'];
}

function add_field() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.setAttribute("id", "input_text" + rowNumber + "_wrapper");
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  input1.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input1.setAttribute("class", "input_text");
  input1.setAttribute("id", "inp1-" + rowNumber);
  p.appendChild(input1);

  var input2 = document.createElement("input");
  input2.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input2.setAttribute("class", "input_text");
  input2.setAttribute("id", "inp2-" + rowNumber);
  p.appendChild(input2);

  createSelect(p, 'sel1', arr1);
  createSelect(p, 'sel2', arr2);
  createSelect(p, 'sel3', arr3);

  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
  btn.setAttribute(
    "onclick",
    'remove_field("input_text' + rowNumber + '_wrapper")'
  );
  p.appendChild(btn);

  document.getElementById("field_div").appendChild(p);
  rowNumber++;
}

function remove_field(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
  calculate();
}

function calculate() {
  var answer = 0;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "";
  var ps = document.getElementById("field_div").getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    if (ps[i].childNodes.length == 0) continue;
    var length = ps[i].childNodes[0].value;
    var width = ps[i].childNodes[1].value;
    var area = length * width;

    var fId = ps[i].childNodes[2].value;
    var func = new Function("supposearea", fId);

    var discount = ps[i].childNodes[3].value;

    var funcId = ps[i].childNodes[4].value;
    var soil = new Function("areas", funcId);

    var amount = area * func(area);
    var soilamount = area * soil(area);

    // ---- CANNOT WORK
    var textdisplay = getTitle(arr1, fId);
    // -- PLS CHECK CHECK HERE----------------------------------------------->
    var statement;
    if (soilamount < 1) {
      statement = "Total Impe ";
    } else {
      statement = "Got Soil";
    }

    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML +=
      "Answer " +
      ++answer +
      ") " +
      area +
      " ----" +
      func(area) +
      "<br>" +
      amount / discount +
      "<br>" +
      soilamount +
      "<br>" +
      textdisplay;
    document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML += statement;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="field_div">
    <input type="button" value="Grass" onclick="add_field();">
  </div>
</div>
<p><button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button></p>
<p id="Result"></p>
<p id="Result1"></p>
```

**Tip** Use specific `id`s for your drop downs. I pass a third input for your `createSelect` function.

Comment: If you copied most of my code with all of my enhancements, you may at least upvote or comment me, don't you think? Anyway, that's nice because my answer is useful to somebody… And you seem to have understand what they wanted without the clarifications I asked for!

Comment: Honey, Me and NoobProgrammer works on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424579/javascript-dynamic-adding-mutiple-drop-down-list/50442655#50442655 and a lot chat we have. @TakitIsy

Comment: I solved his question https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjXWYa and he just did not understand my answer there @TakitIsy

Comment: Honey? Just for that, I won't apologize, ahah! x) Anyway, I don't care about your history. But you answered 20 minutes after me, using most of my enhancements. That looked strange, don't you think? But I won't pursue you, keep calm!…

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee can you take a look at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171446/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-noobprogrammer

Answer (score 1):

I did the following modifications/enhancements in your code:
(I know that doesn't answer the question for the moment, but I am waiting for your clarifications.)

1. Changed `id` to `className`, as you shouldn't have multiple identical ids,
2. Moved the `array`s outside of their functions,
3. Removed the "duplicate" functions and added a second parameter to the remaining one.

See snippet with my comments for more details:

```js
var rowNumber = 0;

// TAKIT: Moved arrays outside of the functions,
// as the functions were similar we'll be only using one!
// (We could rename those arrays to have a meaningfull variable name)
var array1 = [{
    title: "10",
    value: "return 10;"
  },
  {
    title: "20",
    value: "return 20;"
  },
  {
    title: "30",
    value: "return 30;"
  },
  {
    title: "40",
    value: "return 40;"
  },
  {
    title: "50",
    value: "50;"
  },
  {
    title: "60",
    value: "60;"
  },
  {
    title: "70",
    value: "70;"
  },
  {
    title: "80",
    value: "return Math.min(Math.max((3/-500*supposearea + 103.7),50.5),60);"
  }
];

var array2 = [{
    title: "Original",
    value: "0.65"
  },
  {
    title: "35% Discount",
    value: "1"
  }
];

var array3 = [{
    title: "No Soil",
    value: "return 0;"
  },
  {
    title: "Soil",
    value: "165.3;"
  }
];


// TAKIT: Added 2nd parameter in this function
function createSelect(tag, array) {
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.className = "select-" + rowNumber; // TAKIT: Changed .id to .className
  tag.appendChild(select);
  // Append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = array[i].value;
    option.text = array[i].title;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}

// TAKIT: Removed the other createSelect1 and 2 functions, they were similar

function add_field() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.setAttribute("id", "input_text" + rowNumber + "_wrapper");
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  input1.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input1.setAttribute("class", "input_text");
  input1.setAttribute("id", "inp1-" + rowNumber);
  p.appendChild(input1);

  var input2 = document.createElement("input");
  input2.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input2.setAttribute("class", "input_text");
  input2.setAttribute("id", "inp2-" + rowNumber);
  p.appendChild(input2);

  // TAKIT: Using the same function for the 3 lines below, with the new 2nd parameter
  createSelect(p, array1);
  createSelect(p, array2);
  createSelect(p, array3);

  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", 'remove_field("input_text' + rowNumber + '_wrapper")');
  p.appendChild(btn);

  document.getElementById("field_div").appendChild(p);
  rowNumber++;
}

function remove_field(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
  calculate();
}

function calculate() {
  var answer = 0;
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "";
  var ps = document.getElementById('field_div').getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    if (ps[i].childNodes.length == 0) continue;
    var length = ps[i].childNodes[0].value;
    var width = ps[i].childNodes[1].value;
    var area = length * width;

    var fId = ps[i].childNodes[2].value;
    var func = new Function("supposearea", fId);

    var discount = ps[i].childNodes[3].value;

    var funcId = ps[i].childNodes[4].value;
    var soil = new Function("areas", funcId);

    var amount = area * (func(area));
    var soilamount = area * (soil(area));

    // -- CANNOT WORK -----------------------------------
    var h = document.getElementById("createSelect"); // TAKIT: null, because id "createSelect" doesn't exist. What are you trying to do?
    var textdisplay = h.options[h.selectedIndex].text;

    // -- PLS CHECK CHECK HERE --------------------------
    var statement;
    if (soilamount < 1) {
      statement = "Total Impe ";
    } else {
      statement = "Got Soil";
    }


    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML +=
      "Answer " + ++answer + ") " + area + " ----" + func(area) + '<br>' + amount / discount + '<br>' + soilamount + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML += statement;

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="field_div">
    <input type="button" value="Grass" onclick="add_field();">
  </div>
</div>
<p><button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button></p>
<p id="Result"></p>
<p id="Result1"></p>
```

Feel free to comment for any modification.

Hope it helps, anyway!